# What are the advantages of using a Base ViewModel class instead of @html.action to supply data to a partial view?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, partial-views, razor-2

I have a partial view I want to render in multiple views that have differing View Models.  The partial view in question is Rendered as part of the layout page:

```
@RenderPage("~/views/shared/_usernavbar.cshtml")
```

As the View Model on the parent page is different each time I can't just put the data I need into the ViewModel for each page and then reference it in the partial.

I want everything to remain strongly typed, so one possible solution is to create a Base View Model which I apply to the layout page and add to the various view models I will be using on the different pages.  I can then reference the Base View Model in my partial.  However, I could also just render my partial using @Html.Action, which would then allow me to call whatever View Model I like in my partial.  Using @Html.Action would also mean I my parent view didn't need to have a View Model attached.

What I would like to know is why would I use a Base View Model over @Html.Action in such a scenario?  As both require a separate server call to generate the data for my partial, is there any downside to using @Html.Action over the Base View Model?

edit - I'll try to add an example as simple as possible.

I have a View that calls the following ViewModel:

```
public class CourseViewModel 
    {
        public int CourseID { get; set; }
        public string Title { get; set; }
        public string Country { get; set; }
    }
```

I have a partial that requires the following viewmodel (data):

```
public class UserInfoViewModel
{
    public int Stars { get; set; }
    public int XP { get; set; }
    public int Level { get; set; }
}
```

In the parent view the first View Model is called:

```
@model IEnumerable<OLTINT.ViewModels.CourseViewModel>
```

The partial view is called on the layout page as follows:

```
@RenderPage("~/views/shared/_usernavbar.cshtml")
```

In reality there are multiple parent views all with different View Models, in each view I want to call the partial view with the data in its View Model.  I can't simply add that data to the parent View Models because then the model I'd call in the partial view would have to be different each time.

I perceive two possible solutions, using a Base View Model as above or calling the partial using @Html.Action.

Comment: Why don't you use a @Html.Partial? Also @Html.Action will not require an aditional server call, these are resolved before the view is sent to the client.

Comment: Overall your question isn't that clear. Perhaps if you create an example of your issue?

Comment: As far as I'm aware I can't use @Html.Partial to call a partial view into another view when both have a different ViewModel.  Is that not the case?

Comment: I'll give it a crack.  As for @Html.Action, by server call I mean I will have to send a second query to the db.  If I was just using a single ViewModel for both the partial and the parent view I would only be sending one query.  Is that not correct?

Comment: It's perfectly fine to send a differnet model to a partial. Providing the parent viewmodel contains the child viewmodel. It all depends on the structure of your objects. We need more details

Comment: The parent view containing the child viewmodel is effectively what I am suggesting with the Base View Model is it not?  What's the difference?

Comment: Also as per the question, the partial is being rendered by the layout page, so I can't simply send the subset of the ViewModel to the partial that I want as there is no model on the layout page.  I believe that's what I'd need to do because otherwise I'd have to call the parent view model on the partial which obviously I can't do as they are all different.

Comment: Layout pages can have models. I've used this often. You define a base model and all my viewmodels must inherit from it. Then the layout can render the model too

Comment: Yes I know, that's what I suggested in my question, one of the possible solutions is to use a Base View Model and apply that to the layout.  My question was, why is that any better than simply using Html.Action to call the partial? Given that both require a separate query to the db to call the data and if I use Html.Action I don't need to always have a viewmodel in my parent view.  Are there any advantages to using a Base View Model over Html.Action?

Comment: Ok thanks for trying to help anyway Liam.

Comment: Tl; Dr it depends. Sometimes a base class is the answer, sometimes it's not. It depends on the exact structure of your system. There is no better, just different

Comment: sounds like you're over thinking this.. just use @Html.Action...

Comment: Well possibly, but that was really the nature of my question, I just wanted to know whether there was something I was missing.  Otherwise @Html.Action just seems like an objectively better solution as it does the same thing but has fewer restrictions on it.  Yet people use Base View Models for similar situations so I assumed I must be missing something.

Answer (score 0):

After reading the comments

As Liam said Partial is to prefer on Action because you call the server once. If you call an Action you are triggering the server twice (2 request). Using partial the controller is hit once.

Hitting twice could incur in more memory use, more db connection used, low request throughput in general more server resources used.

Using your example, if you need to retrieve `UserInfoViewModel` data for every parent model, it could cause your application to do N+1 query to database (this could be a problem, if you have more than "some" users or you are not using cache).

A more common approach could be to retrieve the whole data needed in the controller using only 1 or 2 query (one for `Courses`and one for all needed `UserInfo`) and aggregating data in the controller.

Comment: Thanks for your response but I'm not sure what you are trying to say.  I can't use @Html.Partial, for the reason already given.  I would need to apply a Base View Model, which means sending two queries to the db just as Html.Action would.  Html.Action would return a partial just the same with the same query to the db as using a Base View Model as far as I can see.  Are you saying that Html.Action is somehow querying the db in a different way to using a Base View Model?  If so in what way?